# Singing English song as a non-English speaker

Tags: lyrics, songwriter

I am not that good at English but me and my friends want to add English songs in our new album.

1.How do you think on that?

2.Could someone recommend me a website that we can buy lyrics?

Thanks

Comment: If your English is good enough to write this question, it's good enough to write lyrics! I think you'll get a lot more satisfaction writing your own lyrics than using someone else's. You could always get someone to check and correct what you've written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many non-native English lyricists have had success with English songs (especially ones from Sweden, for some reason: ABBA, Roxette, Ace of Base, Cardigans, *etc.*).  I often find those lyrics to be a bit odd or "off" but in an appealing way.  Non-native speakers often phrase things in unusual ways that can help their lyrics stand out from the crowd.

If you do want to find an English lyricist, http://co-writers.com is a free place to find a writing collaborator. For paid gigs, http://fiverr.com is a low-cost crowdsourced website for all kinds of odd jobs.  A listing on http://craigslist.org might also bring in some takers.  There are many other freelancer websites as well at higher price points.

Finally, I'm actually a lyricist myself.  My email is in my profile if you want to contact me.

Comment: The Scorpions, too.  The main problem is enunciation; if your listeners can't understand the words it's not going to matter what language you're singing in.